# ReactDOM seems to be caching and releasing elements, so is this a leak?

Tags: reactjs, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, react-dom

I think I lost most of my weekend and a few nights sleep to what might be a non-issue.

While tracking a memory leak in our AngularJS/React hybrid web application, I did the procedure I've done for many, many years: Start in state A, go to state B, return to state A, force garbage collection and check for leaks.

It took far too long (perhaps because I was just trying to run the test quickly) for me to realize that ReactDOM seems to be caching elements and releasing them over time. So when I force GC, it doesn't really garbage collect all the freeable objects. If I wait a few seconds and try again, more stuff gets freed.

Interestingly, I'm finding that I have an `HTMLSelectElement` that seems to hang around the longest. If I wait a little bit, it too gets released.

What is going on, and is there any way to configure React to make finding memory leaks less painful?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No it is getting garbage collected so its not a memory leak.
You can move onto comparison from "summary" and compare it with previous snapshot to check for the delta of the leaked objects.
Generally if two snapshots are increasing in size , then they signify memory leak.